# The Java compiler does not allow usage of an annotation with `Source` retention from a `compileOnly` module for a project using JPMS

Tags: java, annotations, java-9

Annotation processors and compiler plugins often define annotations with `source` or `class` retention. These annotations are not exposed at runtime, thus there is no need to include them in the runtime classpath; they can be used via `compileOnly` in a Gradle build file. Additionally, there is no need to declare their use in the `module-info` file. Yet, in the presence of a `module-info` file, the Java compiler requires the annotation classes to be included in the runtime classpath -- they must be declared in the module-info, which means they must be accessed from Gradle with `implementation` instead of `compileOnly`. This appears to be a hole in the compiler's support for JPMS.  Or, is there a good explanation for this odd behavior?

Here's an example.

```java
package com.example;
...

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Example {
...
}
```

The `com.example.Example` annotation is defined in dependency `my-annotation-proc`.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.example:my-annotation-proc:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'com.example:my-annotation-proc:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Usage of `ExampleAnnotation` in Foo.java.

```java
package abc;

public class Foo {
  
  @com.example.Example
  public void something() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The `module-info.java` file should **not** need a `requires` for usage of the annotation.

```java
module MyProject {
  // Should be no need for this. 
  // Plus, adding it requires an `implementation` dependency in Gradle, which brings it into runtime where it does not belong.
  //requires my.annotation.proc;
}
```

Compiling the project produces a compile error indicating the `com.example` is not visible etc.

Comment: Related Q&As: [Does the Java 9 Module system support optional dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39900460/6395627) | [What's the difference between requires and requires static in module declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46537294/6395627) | [Why do we need requires static in java-9 module system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56170361/6395627)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `requires` directive is mandatory for *any* dependency, not just runtime dependencies.

Compare with [JLS, §7.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.1):

> #### 7.7.1. Dependences
>
> The `requires` directive specifies the name of a module on which the current module has a dependence.
>
> …
>
> The `requires` keyword may be followed by the modifier `static`. This specifies that the dependence, while mandatory at compile time, is optional at run time.

I don’t know whether using `requires static my.annotation.proc;` solves your problem with Gradle, but that’s how it is supposed to be handled at the language level.

Comment: It should fix the problem with Gradle. [The documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#declaring_module_dependencies) shows `compileOnly` corresponds to `requires static`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. In other words RTFM ;)  Thanks for the quick feedback!